# Output files in C

Tags: c

I apologise if this is a trivial/stupid question but I'm new to programming and don't quite understand file outputs in C.

I've written some code and the bits to do with the output file are here:

```
FILE *output_path;
output_path=fopen("myfile.out", "w");
  .
  .
  .
fprintf(output_path, "%lf\n", x);
```

What I would like to do is view my output but I don't know how to open this file or even locate where it is on my computer. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you provide the full code and the environment in which you are working linux or windows?

Comment: `myfile.out` will probably be located in your working directory.  Are you on Linux or Windows?  If you're on Windows, are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I would guess it is in the same directory as the executable file being generated.

Comment: @csnate is it possible to create and read a file with a .out extension???? In linux it automatically creates it right on compilation?

Comment: I'm working in windows. I've written my code in Programmer's Notepad and then compiled and ran it in PuTTY. (I'm not sure if that helps)

Comment: @xxx The filename suffix is irrelevant, it does not limit the content to something. "out" does not mean that it is a program, it could be music or a email or [insertanything] as well.

Comment: @joe.bloggs If the file is empty, check if you´re missing a fclose in your program.

Comment: I've saved my code as "prog4.c" in a folder on my desktop. Should my output file also be in this folder?

Comment: @joe.bloggs It depends on where the compiled program is. The source file is irrelevant.

Comment: So you ran it in Linux.  Where ever you compiled and ran your code on the Linux machine probably has the `myfile.out`.

Answer (score 2):

`myfile.out` will be created in your [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Normally its the directory where you get you program executed unless you have changed it with [chdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir)

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP is running the program on PuTTY, the `cat` command should do the trick.
After execution of the program, run `cat myfile.out` to see the contents of the file **myfile.out**